# Rank of operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector $v$ in a n-dimensional vector space $V$, I am trying to determine the rank and eigenvectors of operator $\hat{Q}$ whose matrix with respect to a given basis is:

$Q_{ij} = v_i v_j $
where $i,j = 1,...,n$

I know the rank is 1, but I'm not sure how to show this? How to infer the dimension of the image space of Q with the above definition? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Q = v v^T$.

Split the space into $\operatorname{sp}\{ v \}$ and $\operatorname{sp}\{ v \}^\bot$, and see how $Q$ operates on each.

To see what ${\cal R} Q$, expand $Qx$ using the above representation for $Q$.

Comment: No, I mean that each element of the space, say $x$, can be written (uniquely in this case) as $x=x_1+x_2$ where $x_1 \in \operatorname{sp}\{ v \}$ and $x_2 \in \operatorname{sp}\{ v \}^\bot$.

Comment: ok. sorry I'm having trouble seeing this. what exactly do you mean by sp{v}⊥? the span of some vectors in V which are orthogonal to those in sp{v}?

Comment: No, $A^\bot = \{ x | \langle x, a \rangle = 0, \forall a \in A \}$, that is the vectors that are orthogonal to all vectors in the set $A$.